# Measuring the inter-winding capacitance of a multi-coil transformer

Tags: transformer, measurement

I want to measure the inter-winding capacitances of a multi coil/winding transformer. (To use them in a simulation)

For a two winding transformer I would measure it by shorting out the individual windings and measure across the transformer with an LCR Meter.

However, for transformers with multiple windings, I think you would always measure capacitances to other windings as well.

What is the correct/best way to measure the capacitances between all windings?

Comment: You are not going to get satisfactory results using an LCR bridge to measure inter winding capacitance.

Comment: Can you elaborate on that? How do I get satisfactory results?

Comment: The reading will be likely "upset" by the winding inductance appearing in series with the interwinding capacitance. I'd probably be thinking of trying to charge the interwinding capacitance up to some dc voltage then watch how this voltage decays into the input impedance (1Mohm) of an oscilloscope. From the rate of decay you can formulate a value. This boils down to using a very slow moving signal as stimulus because a slow moving signal will not produce as many errors due to inductance of the windings.

Comment: @Andyaka: Keep in mind that it's the *effective capacitance at the operating frequency* that the OP is interested in. Using an LCR bridge at that frequency (or range of frequencies) would in fact be the ideal way to measure that.

Answer (score 1):

There are two common ways that transformers are wound. The first method, which is typical of power transformers, is that each winding is a separate layer. In this setup, a winding will have significant capacitance only to the one or two windings immediately adjacent to it. It will essentially be electrostatically "shielded" from the other windings. In order to figure out the construction of such a transformer (if it isn't otherwise obvious), I would ground all of the unused windings when measuring the capacitance of a specific pair. Then you can infer the sequence of layers from the pairs that show significant capacitance.

The second method, which is typical of signal transformers, is to use a "multi-filar" technique in which all of the windings are twisted together and wound simultaneously onto the core. In this setup, the mutual capacitance among any given pair of windings will be the same as any other, which simplifies the measurement problem.

Comment: My transformer is built in layers, but my two secondary windings (center tap) are wound bi-filar. Additionally I have two auxiliary windings on top of that.

Comment: In that case, the simplifying techniques that I suggested above don't apply. Your best bet is to wire the transformer up the same way it will be used in the circuit (I assume that at least some of the terminals are grounded), and then use a network analyzer to derive the model parameters (capacitance, inductance, resistance). Just how precise does your simulation model need to be?